# Angular 4 Data is not getting displayed in table

Tags: angular

Trying an example in angularjs 4 to display the list of items in bootstrap table, I am loading the data from the .json file and trying to display using bootstrap table the table header is displaying properly but the data is not getting displayed let me know if I am making any mistakes

Here is the code,

Below is the component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'drivers-list',
  templateUrl: './drivers-list.component.html',
  
})
export class DriversListComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: any[];
    public filterQuery = "";
    public rowsOnPage = 10;
    public activePage = 1;
    public sortBy = "email";
    public sortOrder = "asc";
    public itemsTotal = 0;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadData();
    }
 
    public loadData() {
        this.http.get("assets/data2.json")
            .subscribe((data) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
 
                    this.data = _.orderBy(data.json(), this.sortBy, [this.sortOrder]);
                    this.data = _.slice(this.data, (this.activePage-1)*this.rowsOnPage, (this.activePage-1)*this.rowsOnPage + this.rowsOnPage);
                    this.itemsTotal = data.json().length;
                }, 2000);
            });
    }
 
    public toInt(num: string) {
        return +num;
    }
 
    public sortByWordLength = (a: any) => {
        return a.city.length;
    }
```

Below is the html file template file,

```html
<div class="col-md-auto">
    <div class="portlet light bordered">
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <table id="table-pagination" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">DRIVER</th>
                        <th data-field="name" data-align="center">LAST ACTIVE</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-align="center">CYCLE</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">GROUPS</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">APP VERSION</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">STATUS</th>
                        <th data-field="price" data-align="center" >ACTIONS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
                        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{item.price}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using `ngFor` to iterate the rows

Comment: Try `<td>{{item?.id}}</td>`

Comment: You can try invoke loadData() in constructor insted ngOnInit.

Comment: @KrzysztofLa I would keep all out from the constructor that doesn't need to be there: [OnInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) ***Don't fetch data in a component constructor. [....] Constructors should do no more than set the initial local variables to simple values***

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes of course but it was just a wild guess. It looks like view is rendered before he gets data... But is should be there because he's getting it from file. So maybe he should convert ngOnInit in Promise way?

Comment: @KrzysztofLa Yes I understand, but then we can use for example safe navigation operator. Even if we put the request in constructor, we can still not make sure that response arrives in time :)

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap table https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/ is not working with angular 4.

Started using the below table

https://github.com/CasperTech/angular2-datatable-pagination

Now every thing is working fine.